# How to create 'Security Role' (role entity) through the REST API?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Here is the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/role?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) where mentioned that you can use different operations on this type of the entity `Operations Supported POST GET PATCH DELETE`. I am interested in using a request to POST.

Can anyone help me with the creation of the role entity?

I tried the request to `POST https://my_org.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/roles` with the body :

```
    {
        "parentrootroleid@odata.bind": "/roles(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000008)"
    }
```

but it failed with the code 400 and response body is :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "0x80040203",
        "message": "businessunitid",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "businessunitid",
            "type": "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.CreateInternal(Entity entity, InvocationContext invocationContext, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.CreateOrganizationResponse(Entity entity)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.CreateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, EdmEntityObject entityObject, Boolean isUpsert)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PostEntitySetImplementation(String& entitySetName, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request requires `businessunitid` in the payload.

```
entity["businessunitid@odata.bind"] = "/businessunits(B08C8C6C-5C20-E511-80F7-C4346BAC59AC)";
```

Comment: If this entity is self-referential, why is it not marked 'hierarchical' in one-to-many relationships?
and the last one
Are there any other entities that have self-referential or cycle dependencies with "RequiredLevel=SystemRequired"?

Comment: @PavloMykhailyshyn there are many varieties, but this one is different. Role is not transactional entity to have hierarchy concept. Role is crucial security piece on BU specific.. so answer is not straight forward, it depends.

Comment: what about this question
Are there any other entities that have self-referential or cycle dependencies with "RequiredLevel=SystemRequired"?